# How to attach the console in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, console, eclipse-kepler

In eclipse the console is somehow undocked. Now it's appearing like below :

[image]

How to attach it to the window? I tried the "pin console" button but nothing happening. I am running eclipse kepler.

Please help.

Comment: Reset perspective should have done your job!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can click `Windows > Reset perspective` to go back to default perspective settings.

Comment: This is not the best answer as it will reset everything you have already setup, See Sriram's answer for best solution

Answer (score 57):

It is just a drag of the pop up window to the main window. Key is to drag by tab title not by main window. In your case, start dragging at tab titled console!

[image: console]

Comment: Why resetting? This is much better. Thanks!

Comment: This is definitely the best answer. The reset perspective option will destroy all other perspective changes including the one that the user wants to maintain

Comment: This approach doesn't work if you have another Eclipse window open; you will have to close other windows before you can drag the tab back to your main window. (As of Eclipse version 4.22.0)

Answer (score 7):

The easiest method that worked for me in *Eclipse Photon* is:

1. Click on the **Open Console** icon present amongst the icons on the console window.

**Open Console icon:**
[image]

2. Click on **New Console View**

**New Console View:**
[image]

This will start a docked version of the current console.
And the one which is detached can be simply closed thereafter.

Comment: Great!  Sometimes you can't drag the tab but you can drag this New Console tag into the worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

Go to WINDOW, then select these submenus:

- SHOW VIEW
- CONSOLE

As in this screenprint:

[image]

that's it

Comment: This is not an answer. As you are new, you cannot comment until you have participated for some time and earned reputation. Stack Overflow is not a bulletin board. You need to answer questions or post your own. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922) before you do.

Answer (score 0):

Window->Perspective->Reset Perspective

Comment: This is the same solution as in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30835841/1519716). _When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers._

Answer (score 0):

Grab on Git Staging icon, drag and drop on console bar:

[image: Grab on Git Staging icon, drag and drop on console bar]

Answer (score -1):

1. From opened Eclipse; go to Window>Perspective>Reset Perspective
2. Back to Window>Show View
3. Click on Console.

I found this convenient.

Comment: This is the same solution as in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30835841/1519716). _When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers._

Answer (score -2):

You can click on Windows > Reset perspective. It will reset perspective settings

Comment: This is the same solution as in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30835841/2227743). *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*